# Alert does not stay open

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

When I execute an alert, the alert shows and disappears too quickly.  I want it to stay open.  What is problem?

After I submit form:

```
 newAlert('success', 'saved');    
 function newAlert(type, message) {
        $('#alert-area').append($("<div class='alert " + type + "'><p> " 
        + message + "             
        </p></div>"));            
 }

 <div id="alert-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not good at jquery, so I try your question with js, its ok. The "alert-area" div did not disappear. This is my code :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="alert-area"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = newAlert('success', 'saved');
    function newAlert(type, message) {       
        document.getElementById('alert-area').innerHTML="<div class='alert " + type + "'><p> " + message + "</p></div>";  
    }
</script>
</body>
<html>
```